# Como receber query params no react com reatc-router-dom?

Tags: react, typescript, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Estou fazendo um App, usando react com typescript e react-router-dom. Porém estou com muita dificuldade para trabalhar com query params nas rotas. Meu objetivo inicial era apenas receber o token e o email que vem na query params.

O token esta vim no seguinte formato:

```
http://localhost:3000/User/ConfirmEmail/?token=asdas&email=fulano@email.com
```

routes.tsx

```
   <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/User/ConfirmEmail/:token"
          component={ConfirmEmail}
        />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

confirmEmail.tsx

```
interface ParamTypes {
  token: string;
  email: string;
}

const ConfirmEmail: React.FC = () => {
  const { token, email } = useParams<ParamTypes>();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(token, email);
  });

  return (
    <>
        {token}
        {email}
    </>
  );
};
```

Estou a dois dias pesquisando sobre, e encontro pouquíssimas pessoas falando sobre um exemplo parecido. O máximo que encontro é exemplos do react-router-dom que esta na documentação dele.
Agradeço a ajuda desde já!

Answer (score 2):

Na documentação explica como faz esse tipo de abordagem em suas variaveis `Query` criando um `Hook` auxiliar da seguinte forma:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function useQuery() {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}

export { useQuery };
```

esse [código está na documentação](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters) e resolvi cria-lo para exemplificação.

Depois disso é só importa o código no seu componente `ConfirmEmail` ficando com o seguinte layout:

```
import React from "react";

import { useQuery } from "../../Hooks";

const ConfirmEmail: React.FC = () => {
  const query = useQuery();
  return (
    <>
      <div>Confirm Email</div>
      <div>{query.get("token")}</div>
      <div>{query.get("email")}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ConfirmEmail;
```

Além do mais o seu arquivo que configura as rotas deve também ter algumas modificações nas configurações das rotas:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./Components/Home";
import ConfirmEmail from "./Components/ConfirmEmail";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/user/confirm-email?token=123456&email=t@t.com">
                Confirm Email
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/user/confirm-email">
              <ConfirmEmail />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/" exact>
              <Home />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

---

- ***Nota:*** nome de rotas coloque todas em minúsculos e se tiver nome composto separados por traço como demonstrados em todos os códigos.
- ***Exemplo:*** [ONLINE da própria documentação](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters)

Comment: Boa tarde, Muito obrigado pela resposta. Me ajudou bastante aqui, vou conseguir evoluir agora com o projeto. Acho que a minha confusão na documentação foi ver 'URL Paramets' em vez de 'Query Paramets', hahaha, vou seguir a dica de colocar as rotas como sugerido. Obrigado!

Comment: @BrunoD.assis se for util vote como resposta da sua pergunta

Answer (score -2):

Segue um exemplo de como criar um hook com typescript

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

export function useQueryParams<T extends Object>(): T {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search)

  let data: { [key: string]: any } = {}

  for (const key of params.keys()) {
    data[key] = params.get(key)
  }

  return data as T
}
```

dessa forma você poderá utilizar em qualquer componente; com tipagem.

por exemplo:

```
type Params = {
  email?: string
}

export function Login() {
  const params = useQueryParams<Params>();

  console.log(params?.email);

  return <Container>...</Container>
}
```

caso você queira receber mais parâmetros basta adicionar no `type Params`, e você terá uma ajudinha da IDE

recomendo que ao adicionar tipos de parâmetros de url na tipagem, coloque este sinal `?` após o nome do propiedade. pois assim você saberá que este valor poderá vir vazio

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).